# Upsampling of pandas dataframe giving warning

Tags: pandas, resampling

```
Order Date  Sales 
2014-01-06  2573.8200
2014-01-07  76.7280
2014-01-10  51.9400
2014-01-11  9.9400
2014-01-13  545.9400
```

I need to upsample sales_df for each day.

```
sales_df.resample('D', how='last').ffill() gives
```

> *FutureWarning: how in .resample() is deprecated the new syntax is .resample(...).last()*

Can someone give the correct syntax or the url of documentation?

Also need the syntax for pad and interpolate

Comment: Use: `sales_df.resample('D').last().ffill()`

Comment: Any url giving examples of the latest syntax on resampling of dataframe?

Comment: [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling)

Comment: sales_df.resample('D', how='last').ffill() results are correct

Comment: yop, if use some old pandas version under `0.18` then yes, it is correct way, else return `FutureWarning`

Comment: sales_df.resample('D', how='last').ffill() does it inplace    sales_df.resample('D').last().ffill() does it on a copy